# \listoftables in appendix

Tags: appendices

I am using an Appendices page which contains a list of tables. If I use `\listoftables`, it doesn't show any of the tables in the appendices. Any idea please?

```
\input{chapter01_introduction}
\input{chapter02_models}
\input{chapter03_results}
\input{chapter04_discussion}
\input{chapter05_conclusions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography
\newpage
\input{appendices}
\section*{Acronyms}
\input{acro_list}
\newpage
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code you have provided does not show any `table` environments. Are there any tables in your document?

Comment: All the tables are within the Appendix section.

Comment: Did you run more than once? `\listoftables` will use data written from the previous run of LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example doesn't show how you're doing things already but here's a table in an appendix followed by a list of tables. Is this the behavior you want?

One caveat is that I don't think you can have multiple lists of tables. If you use \listoftables elsewhere in your document, the list of tables in the appendix will be empty.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Main}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Dummy}
\label{ch:dummy}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{This is a caption}
\label{table:table_lbl}
\center
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\listoftables

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tables in the main report as well as the appendix and none of them are showing in the list of tables. It just shows a page with a heading table list with nothing displayed.

Comment: The above code works for me to show a list of tables. Did you try it by itself? Does it work? You should put up a MWE of what's not working if this works and yours doesn't

Comment: Your example works okay for me.